# Copy the kendo-chip content on click of chip in angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I want to copy the content in kendo-chip on click of chip in angular.please help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZsJ8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Setup a ViewChild on your component that references the ChipComponent
2. Setup the Click event on your ChipComponent
3. In the Click event handler, get the ViewChild's element's nativeElement's innerText value

Example:

```typescript
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { ChipComponent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';

@Component({
  template: `<kendo-chip #kendoChip label="Kendo Chip" (click)="onClick()"></kendo-chip>`,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('kendoChip') kendoChip: ChipComponent;
  onClick(): void {
    console.log(this.kendoChip.element.nativeElement.innerText);
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxtxkt